# Function which takes a string as input and returns the most frequent character

Tags: c++

I wrote a feature. And it works correctly. But in my opinion it is not optimal. But I have not found what standard features you can use to unleash it. Since I made it a simple sort of values. And it takes a long time to execute.

```
char getMaxOccuringChar(char* str)
{
    int count[ASCII_SIZE] = {0};

    int len = strlen(str);
    int max = 0;
    char result;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        count[str[i]]++;
        if (max < count[str[i]]) {
            max = count[str[i]];
            result = str[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, you could keep temporary values of `x = str[i]` and `y = count[x]`, in order to reduce the number of memory-access operations.

Comment: If your string is huge, it's probably more efficient to loop through `count` once to determine the max element at the end instead of doing the `if (max < count[str[i]]) { ` for every character in the string.

Comment: `count[str[i]]++; ` are you sure this is what you want? and not str[i] - 'a' or -'A' ? to map it correctly to an index within your count array?

Comment: BTW, you may as well tag this question `C`, as there is no `C++` syntax involved here.

Comment: What if len equals zero? Why `char*` iso `std::string_view` (or `const char *` pre 17)? What makes you think this ain't optimal?

Comment: @JVApen Because I think it is possible to use some functions rather than to walk and to look in cycles by yourself. But I have not found any that can be used.

Comment: @SamerTufail The explanation in your comment is either inverted, or confusing: `str[i]` *must* be converted to an unsigned int, otherwise it risks being out of bounds, because `char` might be signed.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph having read it again, confusing probably, none the less it requires conversion to an unsigned int, which makes the above code wrong. Would horribly fail on a lot of test cases.

Comment: This looks exactly like [this GeeksForGeeks solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-maximum-occurring-character-in-the-input-string/) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here’s how I’d write this using the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string_view>

char most_frequent_char(std::string_view str) {
    std::unordered_map<char, int> counts;
    for (auto c : str) counts[c] += 1;
    return std::max_element(
        begin(counts), end(counts),
        [](auto a, auto b) {return a.second < b.second;}
    )->first;
}
```

But to be honest I’m not happy with manually iterating over the string to counts its characters. In actual code I’d probably abstract away the creation of a *frequency table*, which would presumably also have a `max` function. In Python this directly corresponds to the `collections.Counter` class. If we assume the existence of this utility class ([left as an exercise to the reader](https://gist.github.com/klmr/b7f6b540ad04d291ccdb842b56b669e2)), the implementation becomes

```
char most_frequent_char(std::string_view str) {
    return max(freq_table{str}).first;
}
```

Incidentally, in statistics this property is known as the *“mode”* of a distribution.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the explicit mentioning of that you use a lambda expression? Assuming the guy  who wrote the question is a beginner, this might not be clear to that person, or the concept might be alien altogether. With the term being explicitly named, one has something to search for.

Comment: @Aziuth 
I'm a girl. I know what lambda is))

Answer (score 2):

We don't modify the passed string, so we should accept a `const char*`.

`ASCII_SIZE` isn't a standard identifier.  A better size for the storage would be `UCHAR_MAX+1` (found in the `<climits>` header).

The counting elements can be unsigned - I recommend `std::size_t`, as that's the maximum length of a string.

Any character greater than `ASCII_SIZE` or less than zero will index out of range, which is undefined behaviour (a bug).

We don't need to call `std::strlen()` to measure the string before we start.  We can just advance the index (or pointer) until we reach the terminating NUL character.

There's a bug if an empty string is passed as argument: in that case, `result` is never assigned, so we return an indeterminate result.

---

## Alternative version

Keeping the existing logic, but fixing the above issues and using a more modern `std::array` instead of a raw (C style) array:

```
#include <array>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdio>               // for EOF

/*
 * Returns the most frequent character, represented as unsigned char.
 * If the string is empty, returns EOF
 */
int getMaxOccuringChar(char const* s)
{
    std::array<std::size_t, UCHAR_MAX+1> count = {};

    std::size_t max = 0;
    int result = EOF;

    while (*s) {
        auto const c = static_cast<unsigned char>(*s++);
        auto current = ++count[c];
        if (max < current) {
            max = current;
            result = c;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

A simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(getMaxOccuringChar("QQMMMX")) << '\n';
}
```

If the input is likely to be more than `UCHAR_MAX` characters, then it may be better to omit updating `max` as we update `count`, and instead find the maximum count after the loop (using `std::max_element()`, from `<algorithm>`).

---

## Multiset version

We could instead use a multiset to count each character (in its constructor), and then use `std::max_element()` to find the mode, like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_set>

/*
 * Returns the most frequent character, represented as unsigned char.
 * If the string is empty, returns the null character
 */
int getMaxOccuringChar(std::string_view s)
{
    auto const count = std::unordered_multiset<char>{s.begin(), s.end()};
    if (count.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    auto const comparator =
        [count](auto a, auto b){ return count.count(a) < count.count(b); };
    return *std::max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), comparator);
}
```

You might find that more satisfying (though performance may suffer through having to re-allocate as the set grows, which isn't a problem when we use an array).

---

## Consider other character types

The second version can be made a template, to work with other character types, such as `wchar_t`:

```
template<typename Char>
Char getMaxOccuringChar(std::basic_string_view<Char> s)
{
    auto const count = std::unordered_multiset<Char>{s.begin(), s.end()};
    if (count.empty()) {
        return Char{};
    }

    auto const comparator =
        [count](auto a, auto b){ return count.count(a) < count.count(b); };
    return *std::max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), comparator);
}
```